# Interrupt JNI method execution in a coroutine

Tags: kotlin, java-native-interface, kotlin-coroutines

I have a JNI method that I want to execute concurrently being able to cancel the coroutine while this method is being executed.

```kotlin
external fun myNativeFunction()
```

I tried using `runInterruptible` but this does not help.

```kotlin
runInterruptible {
    myNativeFunction()
    // The coroutine is cancelled only when it reaches here
}
```

Is there a way to cancel the execution of a JNI method without waiting for it to finish?

Comment: Are you trying to actually interrupt the work being done internally in the native code? Or do you just want the ability for your coroutine Job to be considered cancelled immediately?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I want the coroutine to be cancelled with a CancellationException thrown, and of course it would be preferable if the native code execution would actually be stopped as I no longer need it in this case

Comment: Seems to me like your native function and the kotlin code that calls it need to share some object (either passed to the native function as an argument, or returned from it) through which the kotlin code can say `cancel` and the native code can ask `isCancelled` and take appropriate action.

Comment: Please note cancellations in Kotlin are cooperative. That means the code itself has to check for cancellations and throw by itself. This is the same for JNI as for Kotlin code. If you don't check the status and you don't invoke any functions that do this (many do), cancellation won't have any effect. You need to pass the `Job` object to JNI and check its status from time to time.